# Need help with $.GetJson

Tags: jquery, wcf

I'm using Jquery with WCF, and I'm struggling with getting values when it's returned as arrays by the WCF service.

Here's my JQuery code:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#Button1').click(function () {
                alert('Getting Data....');
                $.getJSON("http://localhost:21030/Service1.svc/GetData", { "strval": "1" }, function (data) {
                 //   $.each(data.d, function (n, val) { alert(val); });
                    alert(data);

                });
            });

        });
```

And here's the JSON that's actually returned by the WCF service...

```
{"d":["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30","31","32","33","34","35","36","37","38","39","40","41","42","43","44","45","46","47","48","49","50","51","52","53","54","55","56","57","58","59","60","61","62","63","64","65","66","67","68","69","70","71","72","73","74","75","76","77","78","79","80","81","82","83","84","85","86","87","88","89","90"]}
```

How can I actually get this array and populate them as a list on the page??

**Edit:** If I keep a breakpoint on the `alert(data)`,the breakpoint doesn't even hit that line. It does not seem to go beyond the `$.getJSON`. Any ideas why?

Comment: Your code should work. Did you run this through Firebug and see what the response is for the AJAX call? You can also replace the `$.getJSON` with `$.get` and see what happens then.

Comment: Do you want to populate generic list on code behind or JavaScript object list?

Comment: looks fine, what isn't working?

Comment: it was working when I returned a single value.After I returned an array,it does not work :(

Comment: `populate them as a list on the page`, wht's tht?

Comment: I meant to add them to an unordered list on the page

Answer (score 0):

Create an unordered list somewhere on your page, I'll assume `#result_list` points to your `ul`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#Button1').click(function () {
            alert('Getting Data....');
            $.getJSON("http://localhost:21030/Service1.svc/GetData", { "strval": "1" }, function (data) {
             var results = data.d;
             var $list = $("#result_list");
             $.each(results, function (result) { $list.append('<li>' + result + '</li>'); });
            });
        });

    });
```